# Feeding image features to tensorflow for training

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

Is it possible to feed image features, say SIFT features, to a convolutional neural network model in Tensorflow? I am trying a tensorflow implementation of [this project](http://richzhang.github.io/colorization/) in which a grayscale image is coloured. Will image features be a better choice than feeding the images as is to the model?
PS. I am a novice to machine learning and is not familiar with creating neural n/w models

Comment: convolutional nets usually operate on Tensors of shape [batch, height, width, channels] where "channels" basically stands for the number of "features" of the image, so it shall be no problem to feed your data into one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can feed tensorflow neural net almost anything.
If you have extra features for each pixel, then instead of using one channel (intensity) you would use multiple channels.

If you have extra features, which are about whole image, you can make separate input a merge features at some upper layer.

As for the better performance, you should try both approaches.
General intuition is that, extra features help if you don't have many samples and their effect is diminishing if you have many samples and network can learn features by itself.

Also one more point: If you are novice, I strongly recommend using higher level framework like keras.io (which is layer over tensorflow) instead of tensorflow.